# Create a Condition For all non empty fields to be ReandOnly - ASP.NET Core 6.0 MVC

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I am developing my first web application with ASP.NET Core 6, and I have a form that shows some fields that I already have information inside of my database.

The problem is: these fields needs to be read-only, because my user needs to considerate the information from my database. If is null, then he needs to insert a value.

Here is an example (consider the field with already set readonly). Most of fields will need this code:

```
<div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-3">
        <label for="Renda Bruta">Associado Desde:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="col-3">
        <label for="Renda Liquida">Cota Capital</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="col-6" style="text-align:center">
        <label for="ServidorPublico">IAP:</label>
        <div class="input-group mb-3">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Quantidade" value="@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.iAP.QuantidadeProduto)" ReadOnly="readonly"/>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Produtos" value=""@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.iAP.Pro)" ReadOnly="readonly"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-4">
        <label for="Renda Bruta">Margem Contribuição</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="col-8" style="text-align:center">
        <label for="ServidorPublico">Cheque Especial</label>
        <div class="input-group mb-3">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Dias de Utilização" />
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Valor Utilizado" />
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Valor Contratado" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I already build the form, and put some fields readonly with `ReadOnly="readonly"`, but is there a way to loop all fields and put readonly with a loop or I really need to write in all fields the code `ReadOnly="readonly" ? My form is really big

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But is there a way to loop all fields and put readonly with a loop or
> I really need to write in all fields the code `ReadOnly="readonly" ?
> My form is really big

Yes, you can set that `ReadOnly` attribute based on the value of your `textbox` field.

In this scenario you have to consider two way, either you should consider your textbox `name` attribute or `type="text"` attribute. Upon these two very way we will be decided which textbox set to `readonly` which is not.

**For [type='text'] Attribute:**

When `[type='text']` means we will check all the textbox type of `text` and check if the textbox have value and set the `readonly` attribute:

View:

```
<div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-3">
        <label for="Renda Bruta">Associado Desde:</label>
        <input type="text" name="Associado" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="col-3">
        <label for="Renda Liquida">Cota Capital</label>
        <input type="text" name="Cota" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="col-6" style="text-align:center">
        <label for="ServidorPublico">IAP:</label>
        <div class="input-group mb-3">
            <input type="text" name="Quantidade" class="form-control" placeholder="Quantidade" value="Test Value" />
            <input type="text" name="Produtos" class="form-control" placeholder="Produtos" value="Test Value Products" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-4">
        <label for="Renda Bruta">Margem Contribuição</label>
        <input type="text" name="Margem" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="col-8" style="text-align:center">
        <label for="ServidorPublico">Cheque Especial</label>
        <div class="input-group mb-3">
            <input type="text" name="Dias" class="form-control" placeholder="Dias de Utilização" />
            <input type="text" name="Utili" class="form-control" placeholder="Valor Utilizado" />
            <input type="text" name="Contra" class="form-control" placeholder="Valor Contratado" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Script:

```
@section scripts {
    <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.3/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("input[type='text']").each(function (index, item) {
                console.log(item);
                if ($(item).val() != "") {
                    $(item).attr('readonly', true);
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

**Note:** When will will set `readonly` to a textbox which has value based on the text type then we have to consider like `input[type='text']`

**For name Attribute:**

```
@section scripts {
    <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.3/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("input").each(function (index, item) {
                console.log(item);
                if ($(item).val() != "") {
                    $(item).attr('readonly', true);
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

**Note:** Remember in this scenario, you need to set `name` property for your textbox to identify uniquely as you can see I have added `name property`

Output:

[image]

Comment: Glad to asist you on this.

Answer (score 0):

what I understand that you want to make the input field enterable when the value of it is null. this is done by javascript.

1. I suggest to make all input fields read only.
2. use javascript to test each field, if its value is null make it enterable.
   for example:

   ```
    <input type="text" id="text1" class="form-control" placeholder="Quantidade" value="@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.iAP.QuantidadeProduto)" ReadOnly="readonly"/>




    <script>
    window.onload = function() {
        if (document.getElementById("text1").value.length == 0)
         {
    document.getElementById("text1").readOnly = false;
    }}
    </script>
   ```

so basically when the page is loading the script will check if the input is null or not and it will do the action.